# Cms Cockpit does not show preview

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cockpit

Cockpit generates an ID (cmsTicketId) related with the session in order to store the preview and show it. The problem seems that the content associated with cmsTicketId is not properly generated and it is empty or does not exist, for this reason  I can not see the preview.

This is very strange because in my local environment sometimes works in Chrome or Opera but never in Firefox.
Anyway is not working anymore in other environmets.

Anyone can give me a clue about what can I do?

Regards,
Martin

**Hybris log:**

```
WARN  16:13:05 [hybrisHTTP21] [] [] [] [ContextInformationLoader] Cannot find CMSSite associated with current URL (https://localhost:9002//previewServlet?cmsTicketId=6475866320580704c9dd84aa-ed00-4fe4-88f1-7e92cd0f95a5)!
```

**Browser log;**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FoundServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=04D8A8EE7DD8DDA58232935EB3A4E712; Path=/; Secure;     HttpOnly
Location: https://localhost:9002/preview-content?uid=md-customer-    communications&cmsTicketId=6475866320722032b3feb2da-29ab-4545-b2a6-8fba42dc4e48
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2016 13:43:57 GMT
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in under Hybris logs ? Or in your JS console ?

Comment: Can you show me your cockpit xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

you should check that the WCMS is "cleaner". Check the URL in the Hybris configuration (via hmc):
- WCMS -> Websites -> WCMS Cockpit Properties
- WCMS Cockpit Preview URL should be contain only your site information or anything; generally it should contain only the following information "?site=mysite" where "site" is the ID (in this case "mysite") of the Website you have currently open.

Best regars,
Gianluigi